# spark dataset : how to get count of occurence of unique values from a column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Trying spark dataset apis which reads a CSV file and count occurrence of unique values in a particular field. One approach which i think should work is not behaving as expected. Let me know what am i overlooking. I am posted both working as well as buggy approach below.

```
// get all records from a column
val professionColumn = data.select("profession")

// breakdown by professions in descending order
// *****  DOES NOT WORKS  ***** //
val  breakdownByProfession = professionColumn.groupBy().count().collect()

// *****  WORKS  ***** //
val  breakdownByProfessiond = data.groupBy("profession").count().sort("count")  // WORKS

println ( s"\n\nbreakdown by profession \n")
breakdownByProfession.show()
```

Also please let me know which approach is more efficient. My guess would be the first one ( the reason to attempt that in first place ) 
Also what is the best way to save output of such an operation in a text file using dataset APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, since there are no grouping columns specified, the entire dataset is considered as one group -- this behavior holds even though there is only one column present in the dataset. So, you should always pass the list of columns to `groupBy()`.

Now the two options would be: `data.select("profession").groupBy("profession").count` vs. `data.groupBy("profession").count`. In most cases, the performance of these two alternatives will be exactly the same since Spark tries to push projections (i.e., column selection) down the operators as much as possible. So, even in the case of `data.groupBy("profession").count`, Spark first selects the `profession` column before it does the grouping. You can verify this by looking at the execution plan -- `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.explain()`

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed explanation, so please confirm if by select-creating a RDD of single column and then doing an action on it would *NOT* result in any performance gain as compared to doing an operation on entire dataset while specifying a column name ?

Comment: In this case, there will not be any performance gain by selecting first. This is because  `select` is pushed down the `groupby`.

Comment: You can look at the explain plans for both alternatives ... i.e., `data.select("profession").groupBy("profession").count.explain` and `data.groupBy("profession").count.explain`. You should notice in both cases that the selection is done first and then the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

In groupBy transformation you need to provide column name as below

```
val  breakdownByProfession = professionColumn.groupBy().count().collect()
```

Comment: So even though the RDD contains one column , do we still need to specify that column in groupby function ? btw i assume you meant `professionColumn.groupBy("profession").count().collect()`